# nw.js - Spawn child_process using nw.js' built-in Node?

Tags: node-webkit

What is the process for spawning a cli through nw.js' own Node? I don't want my users to have to have Node.js installed.

I've tried:

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process");
const child = spawn(process.execPath, ['node_modules/newman/bin/newman.js', 'run'], {
    shell: true,
    stdio: ['inherit']
});
```

This gives me the error "newman '"node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

**Context:**

I have built a nw.js app that acts as a GUI for a cli tool ([newman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman)).

Current behavior: When a button is clicked, child_process spawns a command, ex. "newman run". Current code snippet:

```
const {spawn} = require("child_process");
const child = spawn('newman run' {
    shell: true,
    stdio: ['inherit']
});
```

This does everything I want... except only as long as Node.js is installed on my machine. I would like to use nw.js' own Node functionality instead. Ex.:

C:\nw\nw.exe

C:\nw\node_modules\newman\bin\newman.js

What adjustments would I need to do to spawn this cli through nw.js' own Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NW.js is not really meant for launching separate Node.js scripts. You cannot use `child_process` to launch a new Node.js script using `nw.exe`.

What you can do is read in the script, then use Node's `VM` module to load the script you want to run: https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

All that said, you really don't need all that to use the `newman` package. Run it as a library, not as a CLI command: https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman#using-newman-as-a-library

Comment: To humor me (running it as a library is the long-term goal but not in the cards immediately): you ought to be able to use child_process to launch the .cmd rather than the .js though, yeah? I haven't been able to get that quite right either.

Comment: No. Take a look at `node_modules/.bin/newman.cmd` and you'll see why. Those scripts rely on Node.js being installed.